# JPA native query and cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, native

Does native query in JPA (`createNativeQuery`) supports caching?
I am filling my own data transfer object because the sql query joins several tables and takes only several columns form them.

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible but *you must use an explicit `.addScalar` or `.addEntity`*.

#### See also

- [Caching SQL query problem](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2373167)
- [Hibernate: Truly Understanding the Second-Level and Query Caches](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)